# How can i store my mobile app location to my mongodb database with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I had a mobile application which is using mobile location how can i store the location to mongo dB database I'm using NodeJS as backend

Answer (score 0):

You can store locations using GeoJSON. (See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#point). And then you can use filters in MongoDB by radius, by distance between two point and etc.

For example we add a new user:

```
db.getCollection('test').insertOne({
    user: 'Some user',
    location: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [ 40, 5 ]
    }
})
```

And then we see the new user:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60dd75f2c9dd1126f93b087f"),
    "user" : "Some user",
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            40.0, 
            5.0
        ]
    }
}
```

But it's not end, we should add an index for filtering by geo:

```
db.getCollection('test').createIndex({
    "location" : "2dsphere"
})
```

For example we need filter by a point with radius and have [4 documents with locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n61dE.png). So we filter by the point and radius:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({
    location: {
        $near: {
            $geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [40.45, 5]
            },
            $maxDistance: 50000
        }
    }
})
```

Results: [2 documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoIUe.png)

Comment: but the location is provided by the app right? then how this is possible?

Comment: Yes, it's right, node.js receives a request with location and then store it to MongoDB

Comment: sorry I didn't get you . the location may vary continuously right? if he/she allows the app to accept the location then how we pass to dB using NodeJS and how we update the same if location changes?

Comment: You can make many requests to backend, maybe every minutes. With requests you send ID, maybe user ID or device ID. You can store location as single field or array

Comment: but what the location data contain ? like as you said a point and coordinates right? but it's not in req.body right ? then how i get the location from the data to API to save the same . I'm new in nodejs

Comment: On mobile app you get a coordinates, I don't know how, maybe using external libs or internal API, I'm not a mobile dev. When you got a coordinates, you send ID and coordinates in HTTP Body to backend. On backend you have an endpoint that receives requests and then processes them